# Ubuntu 20.04 not powering off

Tags: 20.04, shutdown, macbook

I have recently installed Ubuntu onto my old (early) 2008 Macbook.

I installed Ubuntu 18 and was all working fine, then I have updated my Ram to 4gb instead of the standard 1Gb.

After this I have updated to Ubuntu 20.04, all seems to be working as it should however, when I power off the machine, it will exit on the screen display with "Ubuntu" at the bottom center and not complete the power off...

is there a solution to fix this?

Comment: Are you saying that it used to power off properly when using Ubuntu 18.04, but does not power off properly when using Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Yes - was working perfectly previous to the update.

Answer (score 0):

1. Test to see if you can reproduce the behavior using a 20.04 LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment. DON'T actually install Ubuntu; just use the "Try Ubuntu" environment.

- **If the 20.04 Try Ubuntu environment powers off properly**, then the issue is specific to your system or some change you have made. More troubleshooting is needed. Alternately, a reinstall seems likely to fix the problem. Don't do Step #2. Stop here.
- **If you can reproduce the behavior in a 20.04 Try Ubuntu environment, then it's a real bug. Move on to Step #2.

2. Test to see if you can reproduce the bug using a pre-release (21.10) LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment.

- **If you can reproduce the bug in 21.10** then the bug is not fixed yet. Look for the bug report on Launchpad.net (`linux` package) and subscribe. If the bug has not been reported, then please report it properly.
- **If you cannot reproduce the bug in 21.10**, then the bug has already been fixed. Look for the bug report on Launchpad.net. When you find it, request that the bugfix be *backported* to 20.04.